# Imported variable undefined inside Svelte component

Tags: jestjs, svelte

This test:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import { setRoutes } from '../router';
import SLink from '../router/components/SLink.svelte';
import routes from '../routes';

beforeAll(() => setRoutes(routes));

test('Instantiates components', () => {
    expect(() => render(SLink, { props: { name: 'About' } })).not.toThrow();
});
```

Produces this error:

```sh
Error name:    "TypeError"
Error message: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

    137 | 
    138 |     const matchRoute = passedRoutes => {
  > 139 |         passedRoutes.forEach(compare => {
        |                      ^
    140 |             if (matchedRoute) return;
    141 | 
    142 |             const { regex, fullRegex } = compare as FormattedRoute;
```

Which comes from this function:

```js
const compareRoutes = (routes, route) => {
    let matchedRoute;

    const matchRoute = passedRoutes => {
        passedRoutes.forEach(compare => {
            // ...
        });
    };

    matchRoute(routes);

    return matchedRoute;
};
```

Which is called by the component I'm trying to render in the test:

```js
<script>
    import { routes } from '../logic';
    import { compareRoutes } from '../static';

    export let name;

    // Error stems from 'routes' being undefined here
    const route = compareRoutes(routes, { name });
</script>
```

---

This line:

```js
beforeAll(() => setRoutes(routes));
```

Sets the routes imported by `SLink` which are then passed to `compareRoutes`, so they shouldn't be `undefined`.

I've used the same line for other functions and the tests run as expected.

Can `@testing-library/svelte` not resolve imports? Or, is there another reason for this?

---

**`setRoutes`:**

```js
let routes;

const setRoutes = (userRoutes) => {
    // ...
    routes = userRoutes;
};

export { routes };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is rendered in JSDom, and I suspect it might not support live bindings like what you're doing with your `export { routes }`.

Try exporting a function instead, to confirm:

```js
export const getRoutes = () => routes
```

Also, this is off topic, but it really feels like your `compareRoutes` function could be simplified as a filter (or map, or reduce) operation. Something like that:

```js
const compareRoutes = (routes, route) => routes.filter(
  x => route.path.startsWith(x.path)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @rixo. Tried exporting the function, but, it gave the same error, unfortunately. The `compareRoutes` function has much more to it, I just removed all the unnecessary logic to make the question more readable